# コマンドプロンプトでイコールを含む名前の変数が定義できることがある理由

Tags: windows, コマンドプロンプト

以下はWindowsのコマンドプロンプトで行った入力とその出力です（`>`の行が入力）。

```
>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]

>set FOO=BAR=BAZ

>echo %FOO%
BAR=BAZ

>echo %FOO=BAR%
BAZ

>set BAZ=BAR=FOO

>echo %BAZ%
BAR=FOO

>echo %BAZ=BAR%
%BAZ=BAR%
```

なぜ`echo %FOO=BAR%`で`BAZ`が返って`echo %BAZ=BAR%`で`FOO`が返らないのでしょうか？
（どちらかというと後者の方が正しい動きに思えますが……バグ？　未定義動作？）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows10 1803で再現しましたが、windows7やW10　1809では再現しません。こっそり直したのでしょうか。

Comment: こちらでもいろいろ試してみましたが、質問と同じバージョン番号の別マシンでは`FOO=BAR=BAZ`で再現せず、代わりに`A=B=C`が再現したり、同じマシンで同じ文字列でも再現したりしなかったりします。やはりバグでしょうか……

Comment: 規則性の無いバグっぽいということで解決済みとします。ありがとうございました。